# remove php tags from a string with python

Tags: php, python

I want to remove php tags from a string

```
content = re.sub('<\?php(.*)\?>', '', content)
```

seems to work OK on single line php tags but when a php tag closes some lines after , it cannot catch it.
can anybody help?

Comment: I think this is beyond the ability of regular expressions and you need an actual parser. For example: `<?php echo '<?php ?>'?>`, `<?php if(1):?>PHP<?php endif?>`, `<? echo 'shorttags!'?>`, `<?=$echos?>`, etc.

Comment: @FrancisAvila just remove <?php * ?> will do my job!

Comment: No it will not. You think it will, but it won't. Try your regex against those test cases.  Also remember that you can omit the final `?>` in php.

Comment: i can check that. but can you solve my first problem??

Comment: You cannot solve this problem with regular expressions. I have added an answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to handle the simple cases, a simple regular expression will work fine.  The `*?` operator in Python regular expressions gives a minimal match.

```python
import re

_PHP_TAG = re.compile(r'<\?php.*?\?>', re.DOTALL)
def strip_php(content):
    return _PHP_TAG.sub('', content)

INPUT = """
Simple: <?php echo $a ?>.
Two on one line: <?php echo $a ?>, <?php echo $b ?>.
Multiline: <?php 
    if ($a) {
        echo $b;
    }
?>.
"""

print strip_php(INPUT)
```

Output:

```
Simple: .
Two on one line:  (keep this) .
Multiline: .
```

**I hope you're not using this to sanitize input,** since this is not good enough for that purpose.  (It's a blacklist, not a whitelist, and blacklists are never enough.)

If you want to handle the complicated cases, such as:

```php
<?php echo '?>' ?>
```

You can still do it with regular expressions, but you may wish to reconsider what tools you are using, since the regular expressions may get too complicated to read.  The following regular expression will handle all of Francis Avila's test cases:

```python
dstr = r'"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"'
sstr = r"'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'"
_PHP_TAG = re.compile(
    r'''<\?[^"']*?(?:(?:%s|%s)[^"']*?)*(?:\?>|$)''' % (dstr, sstr)
)
def strip_php(content):
    return _PHP_TAG.sub('', content)
```

**Regular expressions** are almost powerful enough to solve this problem.  The reason we know this is because PHP uses regular expressions to tokenize PHP source code.  You can read the regular expressions PHP uses in `Zend/zend_language_scanner.l`.  It's written for Lex, which is a common tool that creates tokenizers from regular expressions.

The reason I say "almost" is because we are actually using extended regular expressions.

Comment: its work in my case but without the `re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE`

Comment: You're right, neither are required.  I forgot to take them out as I was playing with the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot solve this problem with regular expressions. Parsing the PHP out of a string requires a real parser that understands at least a little PHP.

**However, you can solve this problem pretty easily if you have PHP available.** PHP solution at the end.

Here is a demonstration of how many ways you can go wrong with your regular-expression approach:

```py
import re

testcases = {
    'easy':("""show this<?php echo 'NOT THIS'?>""",'show this'),
    'multiple tags':("""<?php echo 'NOT THIS';?>show this, even though it's conditional<?php echo 'NOT THIS'?>""","show this, even though it's conditional"),
    'omitted ?>':("""show this <?php echo 'NOT THIS';""", 'show this '),
    'nested string':("""show this <?php echo '<?php echo "NOT THIS" ?>'?> show this""",'show this  show this'),
    'shorttags':("""show this <? echo 'NOT THIS SHORTTAG!'?> show this""",'show this  show this'),
    'echotags':("""<?php $TEST = "NOT THIS"?>show this <?=$TEST?> show this""",'show this  show this'),
}

testfailstr = """
FAILED: %s
IN:     %s
EXPECT: %s
GOT:    %s
"""

removephp = re.compile(r'(?s)<\?php.*\?>')

for testname, (in_, expect) in testcases.items():
    got = removephp.sub('',in_)
    if expect!=got:
        print testfailstr % tuple(map(repr, (testname, in_, expect, got)))
```

Notice that it's extremely difficult, if not impossible to get a regular expression to pass all test cases.

**If you have PHP available you can use PHP's tokenizer to strip out the PHP.**  The following code should strip *all* PHP code out of a string *without fail*, and should cover all strange corner cases as well.

```php
// one-character token, always code
define('T_ONECHAR_TOKEN', 'T_ONECHAR_TOKEN');

function strip_php($input) {
    $tokens = token_get_all($input);

    $output = '';
    $inphp = False;
    foreach ($tokens as $token) {
        if (is_string($token)) {
            $token = array(T_ONECHAR_TOKEN, $token);
        }
        list($id, $str) = $token;
        if (!$inphp) {
            if ($id===T_OPEN_TAG or $id==T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO) {
                $inphp = True;
            } else {
                $output .= $str;
            }
        } else {
            if ($id===T_CLOSE_TAG) {
                $inphp = False;
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

$test = 'a <?php //NOT THIS?>show this<?php //NOT THIS';


echo strip_php($test);
```

Comment: I appreciate the practical answer alongside an explanation of why regex won't suffice. Nice.

Comment: I've posted a regular expression that handles all your test cases.  I suspect like most tokenizers, the PHP tokenizer is built on regular expressions in the first place.  By using the PHP tokenizer you save yourself the work of writing the regular expressions, but you are still actually using regular expressions.

Comment: If you're curious, you can read the regular expressions that PHP uses in the PHP source code file `Zend/zend_language_scanner.l`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it through this:

```
content = re.sub('\n','', content)
content = re.sub('<\?php(.*)\?>', '', content)
```

**updated answer after OP's comments:**

```
content = re.sub('\n',' {NEWLINE} ', content)
content = re.sub('<\?php(.*)\?>', '', content)
content = re.sub(' {NEWLINE} ','\n', content)
```

example in `ipython`:

```
In [81]: content
Out[81]: ' 11111  <?php 222\n\n?> \n22222\nasd  <?php asd\nasdasd\n?>\n3333\n'

In [82]: content = re.sub('\n',' {NEWLINE} ', content)
In [83]: content
Out[83]: ' 11111  <?php 222 {NEWLINE}  {NEWLINE} ?>  {NEWLINE} 22222 {NEWLINE} asd  <?php asd {NEWLINE} asdasd {NEWLINE} ?> {NEWLINE} 3333 {NEWLINE} '

In [84]: content = re.sub('<\?php(.*)\?>', '', content)
In [85]: content
Out[85]: ' 11111   {NEWLINE} 3333 {NEWLINE} '

In [88]: content = re.sub(' {NEWLINE} ','\n', content)
In [89]: content
Out[89]: ' 11111  \n3333\n'
```

Comment: and how to reverse unwanted changes to \n??

Comment: You have right! You can use a solution of replace the new line with `something` that is unlikely to be included in your file. Then run the regular expression so as to filter out the php tags. Finally, replace `something` with newline.

Comment: i'm sorry but it removes all the string. it return a string containing just one \n and nothing else, maybe the the whole string catched with the second line.

Comment: thanks, my real test is more complex than your tests and results in blank string

Comment: why I got -1? I proposed a simple solution that works for a not so complicated input..